# Manage <li> selected state

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `<ul>` element that contains a few li-elements:

```
<ul id="ul">
  <li id="li1"></li>
  <li id="li2"></li>
  <li id="li3"></li>
</ul>
```

**I want to:**

1. Add 'selected' class to `<li>` element when I click on it
2. Clear all 'selected'-class attributes from all `<li>` elements except `<li>` that have been just clicked

**Question:**

How can I do that?

Comment: You can achieve this. Add a click event handler to your elements and use jQuery's `addClass()` and `removeClass()` methods to add/remove class.

Comment: (-1) please read a few jQuery tutorials and do some googling before asking.  These are all basic jQuery concepts.

Comment: this looks like homework

Comment: With jQuery. I would start here: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/, http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/, http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/, http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/css-styling-dimensions/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple (**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bRAUu/)**):

```
<ul id="ul">
  <li>Item 1</li> <!-- id is unnecessary here -->
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#ul>li').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('selected'); // set "selected" class to clicked item
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected'); // remove "selected" class from other li's
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vA3Zp/4/)

**CSS**

```
  p { margin: 4px; font-size:16px; font-weight:bolder;
      cursor:pointer; }
  .blue { color:blue; }
  .highlight { background:yellow; }
```

**HTML**

```
  <p class="blue">Click to toggle</p>
  <p class="blue highlight">highlight</p>
  <p class="blue">on these</p>
  <p class="blue">paragraphs</p>
```

**JS**

```
    $("p").click(function () {
    $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight")
      $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
    });
```

Comment: in my case $(this) point to ul-element instead of  li-element

Answer (score 1):

Just a sample to help you on your way. Check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/P8MSj/) for a sample with jQuery. For a pure JS version (without jQuery) [**click here**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/AyaNP/).

The following is what you have to do to achieve what you want.

1. Create a CSS class (say `selected`) and add your rules to it (like below).

**CSS**

```
.selected{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

1. Using jQuery, create a `click` event handler for your `li` elements.
2. Use `removeClass()` method to remove the `selected` class from all elements whenever an `li` element is clicked. Then using `addClass()` method add the `selected` class only to your `li` element that has been clicked.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ul li').click(function(){
        $('#ul li').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#ul li").click(function () {
        $("#ul").children().removeClass("select");
        $(this).addClass("select")
    })
});
```